# Is it possible to create a universal suppression audience?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

So, I'm trying to create a suppression/exclusion for specific users that can automatically be suppressed from emails without having to manually select that table/DE to each Campaign.

For example, I might want to exclude Bounced users on ALL emails without having to put them into the Exclusion bucket.

Or, I want to always suppress a field indicating users are in a Journey from every non-journey send.

Is there a way to have a universal suppression across all batch email sends?

I'm mostly thinking ahead here. Over time we'll be adding more team members and a larger scale, and want to make sure we can minimize mistakes or extra steps in the send process.

Comment: talk to support, I believe this is an option that is available. This is to support if you choose not to have SFMC as your DBoR (Database of Record).

Answer (score 0):

In Marketing Cloud there is an automatic process to exclude email addresses bounced in an email send. The subscriber status will change in All subscriber list following the rules explained in the diagram that you can find in the link of documentation [Bounce management](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/bounce_mail_management/)

At the same time if you want to exclude email addresses with a history of spam complaints, unsubscribe lists from previous providers or advertisers, addresses of your competitors, and canceled customers, you could use the [“Auto-Suppression List”](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/auto_suppression_lists/) that allow you to exclude automatically the contacts imported in this list. This feature does not require to select this list in each email send.